# Is there a concise syntax for chaining yield calls in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, yield

I have a method that iterates over some records and does something with them, optionally yielding a result -- something analogous to:

```
@evens = []
def foo(numbers)
  numbers.each do |r|
    even = r % 2 == 0
    @evens << r if even
    yield "#{r}: #{even}" if block_given?
  end
end
```

I have a second method that fetches records and passes them to the first method, something analogous to:

```
def bar(count)
  numbers = (0..count).to_a
  foo(numbers)
end
```

I want to change this method to also take an optional block, yielding the results from the first method. What I've come up with so far:

```
def bar(count)
  numbers = (0..count).to_a
  foo(numbers) do |result|
    yield result if block_given?
  end
end
```

This feels like about two more lines and one more `if block_given?` check than I ought to need. Is there a more concise way to simply say "yield whatever this method call yields, if anything"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When defining a method in Ruby, you can also optionally define the block as a special named argument:

```
def bar(count, &block)
  #...
end
```

Then, in the method, you can pass the block (or generally: any Proc object) as a block to a method. Thus, the following method will be fully equivalent to your `bar` method:

```
 def bar(count, &block)
  numbers = (0..count).to_a
  foo(numbers, &block)
end
```

Note that even when defining a `&block` argument in the method's signature, it is not mandatory to pass a block. If you don't pass one, `block` will be `nil` in the method body.

Comment: Well I'll be, the darn thing just works. Maybe not the most readable thing for a total ruby newbie to come across, but it does what it says on the tin. Thanks!